# Autopilot (ceph/ceph) how is space allocated?

Tags: partitioning, juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I have 5 machines deployed, maas server, landscape server, and node01,02,03.

Each Node is identical, 8 cores, 32gb ram, 3 HDs for 1gb per machine, (146, 300, 600gb 15k drives).  maas and landscape both have 72gb drives.

Landscape is reporting 3tb for all the nodes, the region reports 2tb usable in ceph.  The defaults within Horizon show 1000gb for volumes and snapshots and 1000gb for backup.

Does it show 2tb because after the data is distributed and replicated, it goes from 3tb to 2tb equivalent to raid5?

Is the 2tb then split 50/50 with the defaults of the system between volumes and backups?

[Landscape Region Hardware List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFVCH.png)

[Landscape Region Hardware Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5rjQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I would answer this having more knowledge in CEPH then when I asked the question.  Although, I can't say why the defaults are the defaults in Horizon.  If they are generated or just a starting place for openstack.

Landscape drive usage is pulled from ceph, which already includes replication.

```
    cluster eabab000-231c-4edb-855c-dd30b1bab56d
     health HEALTH_OK
     monmap e2: 3 mons at {juju-machine-0-lxc-4=10.14.0.53:6789/0,juju-machine-1-lxc-0=10.14.0.62:6789/0,juju-machine-2-lxc-4=10.14.0.60:6789/0}
            election epoch 12, quorum 0,1,2 juju-machine-0-lxc-4,juju-machine-2-lxc-4,juju-machine-1-lxc-0
     osdmap e358: 13 osds: 13 up, 13 in
      pgmap v324244: 1091 pgs, 14 pools, **132 GB data**, 35396 objects
            **378 GB used**, 3636 GB / **4014 GB avail**
                1091 active+clean
  client io 1740 B/s wr, 0 op/s
```

As you can see, there is a total of 132GB of data spread across the 14 pools.  In my case, cinder contains 99% of the usage data.

```
ubuntu@juju-machine-0-lxc-4:~$ sudo ceph df
GLOBAL:
    SIZE      AVAIL     RAW USED     %RAW USED 
    4014G     3636G         378G          9.42 
POOLS:
    NAME                                         ID     USED     %USED     MAX AVAIL     OBJECTS 
    rbd                                          0         0         0         1126G           0 
    .rgw.buckets                                 1      1894         0         1126G           2 
    .rgw.root                                    2       848         0         1126G           3 
    .rgw.control                                 3         0         0         1126G           8 
    .rgw.gc                                      4         0         0         1126G          32 
    .rgw.buckets.index                           5         0         0         1126G           1 
    .rgw.buckets.extra                           6         0         0         1126G           0 
    .log                                         7         0         0         1126G           0 
    .intent-log.usage                            8         0         0         1126G           0 
    .users.users.email.users.swift.users.uid     9         0         0         1126G           0 
    glance                                       10     500M      0.01         1126G          68 
    .rgw                                         11      404         0         1126G           2 
    .users.uid                                   12      417         0         1126G           3 
    cinder                                       13     132G      3.30         1126G       35277
```

132GB is actual data, but there is 378GB used.  That's becuase of the replication level.

```
ubuntu@juju-machine-0-lxc-4:~$ sudo ceph osd dump | grep -i cinder
pool 13 'cinder' **replicated size 3** min_size 2 crush_ruleset 0 object_hash rjenkins pg_num 166 pgp_num 166 last_change 358 flags hashpspool stripe_width 0
```

Our total space is simply calculated from USED x Replication Level.  So, Horizon is displaying the correct space, 378GB / 4TB available.  Every 100GB file, counts against 300GB space.